# check_box in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have two checkboxes that need to be exclusive.

```
%p Are you a Borrower or Lender?
        = f.check_box :borrower, {}, "true", "false"
        Borrower
        = f.check_box :lender, {}, "true", "false"
        Lender
```

How do you I change this so user can only select either `borrower` or `lender` option? As currently is, one could check both boxes.

EDIT #2:

So, from what I understand, I need to give the radio_button the same name in order to not confuse the browser and then define a method. Please provide some guidance on how to write such a method.

```
= f.radio_button(:lender_or_borrower, :lender)
Lender
= f.radio_button(:lender_or_borrower, :borrower)
Borrower
```

Comment: Determine if one is checked, and if it is, uncheck it before you check the other one.

Comment: When one checkbox becomes checked, determine if the other checkbox is already checked. If it is, uncheck it before checking the current checkbox. That's pretty standard practice.

Comment: I want the user to be able to check only one. Maybe use radio_button instead? thanks.

Comment: Right. I'm telling you to write code that matches what I'm saying. I'm not telling you to make the user do that.

Comment: Hehe OK, my bad. Any idea on how I could implement this?

Comment: added explanation to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, since it semantically only makes sense to have one option selected at a time, you should either use a select or radio_buttons. 
For example a select could look like this:

```
f.select(:borrower_or_lender, [['Borrower, borrower'],  ['Lender', 'lender']])
```

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models

Edit: As for radio buttons: both radio buttons need to have the same method/attribute (the first argument you pass to the helper):

```
= f.radio_button(:borrower_or_lender, 'borrower')
Borrower
= f.radio_button(:borrower_or_lender, 'lender')
Lender
```

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#radio-buttons or http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button

Comment: OK, first of all thanks! that helped. Second, i've decided to go the radio_button route and I'll update my answer with the new code. However, I still can't figure out how to create a method that will make rails choose one or the other.

Comment: @liroy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions